# How to print A4 papers by HP Deskjet 1010

Tags: printing, hp-deskjet

Recently I've bought an inkjet printer **HP Deskjet 1010**. Previously I had a printer. I usually print with A4 papers. But I can't print A4 documents with the printer. It supports only letter size. I go to printer settings and then click ***Preferences*** and then ***Advanced***. Then I choose A4 as paper size. But still it can't print A4 papers. The lower portion of the paper isn't printed.

I tried to add the screenshots but I can't because I've not 10 reputations.

Comment: Check the page setup in whatever application you are printing from.  It might be set to A4 there.

Comment: I set it A4.. I printed from MS word and set the page size to A4. problem is that the lower portion of the document isn't printed.. The printer prints like a letter size paper.. height of A4 is 11.69 and letter is 11 inch.. the rest .69 inch isn't printed

Comment: As a first step, I would reinstall the printer driver.  Download the most recent version from the HP web site.  The 1010 is an antique.  Any chance that the problem is a defect in the printer?  Other than those two things, I can't think of anything else that could cause it.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's a deskjet, not laserjet.

Comment: An infinite number of numbers to pick from and HP had to reuse the same number for a different printer.  Maybe they didn't want to use up all the numbers.

Comment: @fixer1234 Laserjet 1010 was one of the best mass market affordable printers so they probably tried to ride on it success. In fact I have one still working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simple [Google search](http://reviewbyconsumer.com/hp-deskjet-1010-printer/) revealed that deskjet 1010 bottom print margin is 14,5mm or close to .69 inches.

Also [HP datasheet](https://store.hp.com/wcsstore/hpusstore/pdf/cx015a.pdf) doesn't say it supports A4 media size.

You can still print on A4 but you have to adjust margins in your documents to fit within physical limitations of your printer.

What I've done is start Word and found out that style guidelines suggest minimum margins of 12.7mm and up to 2.54cm or 1 inch for standard documents, so if you follow these you should be within print range.

Comment: Good catch--it doesn't do borderless printing.

Answer (score 1):

I had to pass someone a copy of an Access database that has some Labels reports designed to print quite a few sheets of Avery labels (or compatible), and the HP 1010 messed up the printing not only on my printer, but also on that person's printer which had previously been OK with the same reports (I had recently modified the reports and re-saved them).

Because of the problem with forced wide bottom margin on HP Deskjet 1010 , we were both wasting a lot of these expensive labels sheets for our non-profit -- the printer was jumping to the next page too early.  My colleague has a different/higher quality HP printer and had never had the problem before receiving my file. It seems that these Access label reports were inheriting the wide margin from the default printer driver specs when I saved the file, even when I wasn't printing.  I found this to be odd!

But there's a fix!  I found that if I made my HP Deskjet 1010 printer NOT be default on my PC (I switched to something else I have available), I was able to adjust the bottom margin on the reports to 0.5 inches and re-save the Access database.  It still goes back to jumping to the next page too early when I print on my HP 1010, but at least I was able to pass a good file to the other PCs in our organization.